# Cancel http.put()/http.get() and return value instead of creating/sending request

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular10, rxjs-pipeable-operators

given the following code:

service:

```
getList(){
    return return this.http.request("put", url_, options_)
}
```

component:

```
submitRequest(reset?){
    this.httpService.getList().subscribe((response) => {
        //if reset return an empty array
        //server cannot return an empty array
    })
}
```

and I want to do something like:

component:

```
submitRequest(reset?){
    this.httpService.getList().pipe(someOperator(() => {
        // if reset DO NOT MAKE HTTP CALL BUT INSTEAD RETURN []
    })).subscribe((response) => {
        //IF reset NO SERVER CALL WAS MADE BUT GOT [] FROM someOperator
        //SERVER RESPONSE ONLY IF NO reset
    })
}
```

how do i achieve this using RXJS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like: `if (reset) return of([])`?

```
submitRequest(reset?){
    if (reset) return of([])

    this.httpService.getList().pipe(someOperator(() => {
        // if reset DO NOT MAKE HTTP CALL BUT INSTEAD RETURN []
    })).subscribe((response) => {
        //IF reset NO SERVER CALL WAS MADE BUT GOT [] FROM someOperator
        //SERVER RESPONSE ONLY IF NO reset
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the `reset` operator to an `Observable<any>` that does *not* emit anything immediately upon subscribing (e.g. not a BehaviorSubject), and then the code can change to:

```
private destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.destroy$?.next();
  this.destroy$?.complete();
}

submitRequest(reset?: Observable<any>){
  let o$ = this.httpService.getList();
  if (reset) {
    o$ = merge(o$, reset.pipe(mapTo([])));
  }
  o$.pipe(
    first(),
    takeUntil(destroy$)
  ).subscribe(response => whatever);
}
```

The subscriber function will

- not be called if your `this` gets destroyed. Otherwise,
- received an empty array if `reset` emits anything before the server response is received. Otherwise
- receive the server response.

In any of these cases the subscription will be cancelled so it will clean itself up.